# Custom messages for php exception handling

Tags: php, arrays, exception, message

I'm using an external file with $errmsg array for displaying errors, like:

```
'app_init' => 'Cannot initialize application',
```

Using conditionals, I call the function to display the message on failure:

```
if(!$condition)
{
$arraywithmessages->functionforfiltering($err,'app_init',$aim);
}
```

...where $err is the array of messages, and $aim is predefined method of publishing error (e-mail, view, etc...)

Now I'd like to make use of Exception Handling, but I don't know where to start. Can anyone help? This doesn't seem to work:

```
try {
if (!$condition) {
throw new Exception('app_init');
}
// continue
} catch (Exception $e) {
$arraywithmessages->functionforfiltering($err,$e->getMessage(),$aim);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to achive but you should remember that try, catch should be used wisely. It should be used for Exceptional situations only. If you don't use them in that way then it's GOTO code.

About exceptions, remmeber that you can extend Exception class and make your own exceptions and catch them in multiple catch blocks, there is also finally block.

About the constructor of Exception. It has the second param which is `$code` you can use it to show proper message.

```
$err = array(0x1 => 'my error app init');

try {
if (!$condition) {
    throw new Exception('app_init', 0x1);
}
// continue
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $err[$e->getCode()]; //it shouldn't be only echo it should do some tries to fix the code close streams etc. not just echo.
}
```

There is also function
`set_exception_handler().` which:

> Sets the default exception handler if an exception is not caught within a try/catch block. Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called.

Consider using it. There are a lot of things that can be found in [manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Well, this seems to cover most of my intention. What I simply tried to achieve, is to replace written messages with an element of an array called by key.

Comment: most? What doesn't it cover? It's better to use codes instead of searching strings. And these codes may be keys for array of messages. That's all.